# ParametricPlot3D of Boy's surface

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, topology

I'm trying to visualize Boy's surface using Bryant's parametrization, as per the [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BoySurface.html) article. However, I'm not sure I understand the parametrization, and I don't know how to implement it when the parameter is complex.

```
z := u + vI
g1 := -(3/2) Im[(z (1 - z^4))/(z^6 + z^3 √5 - 1)]
g2 := -(3/2) Re[(z (1 + z^4))/(z^6 + z^3 √5 - 1)]
g3 := Im[(1 + z^6)/(z^6 + z^3 √5 - 1)] - 1/2
g = g1^2 + g2^2 + g3^2

ParametricPlot3D[{g1/g, g2/g, g3/g}, {u, 0, 0.5}, {v, 0, 0.5}]
```

Now, I understand that $z=u+v\mathrm{i}$ is the parameter, and that it must range over the closed unit disc, so $u^2+v^2\leq1$. But I don't know how do do this! (I let $u,v$ range between 0 and 0.5, for good measure, but the graphic appears empty.)

In the end, I want to end up with exactly [this image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/BoysSurfaceTopView.PNG), for which I've been unable to find the original code.

**Edit:**
The 3 solutions provided here worked like a charm (with the caveat that the one using polar coordinates was weirdly sharped, and I couldn't fix that, but I'm a *Mathematica* newb), and I found another method:

```
ParametricPlot3D[Boys[u, v], {u, v} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

I don't know why, but using `RegionFunction` the surface rendered ~30% slower, and, using `Piecewise`, about %5 slower. The only issue is that the mesh is now weirdly triangulated.

Also, I compiled the actual parametric formula and performance increased threefold:

```
Boys = Compile[{u, 
v}, {(-(3/2)
    Im[((u + v I) (1 - (u + v I)^4))/((u + 
      v I)^6 + (u + v I)^3 Sqrt[5] - 1.)])/((-(3/2)
     Im[((u + v I) (1 - (u + v I)^4))/((u + 
       v I)^6 + (u + v I)^3 Sqrt[5] - 1.)])^2 + (-(3/2)
     Re[((u + v I) (1 + (u + v I)^4))/((u + 
       v I)^6 + (u + v I)^3 Sqrt[5] - 1.)])^2 + (Im[(
    1 + (u + v I)^6)/((u + v I)^6 + (u + v I)^3 Sqrt[5] - 1.)] - 
   1/2)^2), (-(3/2)
    Re[((u + v I) (1 + (u + v I)^4))/((u + 
      v I)^6 + (u + v I)^3 Sqrt[5] - 1.)])/((-(3/2)
     Im[((u + v I) (1 - (u + v I)^4))/((u + 
       v I)^6 + (u + v I)^3 Sqrt[5] - 1.)])^2 + (-(3/2)
     Re[((u + v I) (1 + (u + v I)^4))/((u + 
       v I)^6 + (u + v I)^3 Sqrt[5] - 1.)])^2 + (Im[(
    1 + (u + v I)^6)/((u + v I)^6 + (u + v I)^3 Sqrt[5] - 1.)] - 
   1/2)^2), (Im[(
   1 + (u + v I)^6)/((u + v I)^6 + (u + v I)^3 Sqrt[5] - 1.)] - 1/
  2)/((-(3/2)
     Im[((u + v I) (1 - (u + v I)^4))/((u + 
       v I)^6 + (u + v I)^3 Sqrt[5] - 1.)])^2 + (-(3/2)
     Re[((u + v I) (1 + (u + v I)^4))/((u + 
       v I)^6 + (u + v I)^3 Sqrt[5] - 1.)])^2 + (Im[(
    1 + (u + v I)^6)/((u + v I)^6 + (u + v I)^3 Sqrt[5] - 1.)] - 
   1/2)^2)}, Parallelization -> True];
```

I also tried compiling each of $g1,g2,g3,g$ separately, but performance was a bit worse.

Comment: Hello! It's g = g1^2+g2^2+g3^2, right?

Comment: Yes! Will correct!

Comment: Your first problem is that `vI` is a different variable name; you need `v I` with a space in between.

Comment: "that it must range over the closed unit disc" - that should have tipped you off to use **polar coordinates**. As I don't have *Mathematica* on hand, try this: `ParametricPlot3D[With[{z = r Exp[I θ]}, (#/(#.#)) &[Re[{I z (1 - z^4), z (z^4 + 1), -(2 I/3) (z^6 + 1)}/(z^6 + Sqrt[5] z^3 - 1) + {0, 0, 1/2}]]], {r, 0, 9/10}, {θ, -π, π}, PlotPoints -> {20, 30}]`

Comment: Yes, I totally missed that!! Thanks!

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.  Idle query Sir, is its conjugate surface also Boy's ?      
ParametricPlot3D[
 With[{z = r Exp[I \[Theta]]}, (#/(#.#)) &[
   Im[{I z (1 - z^4), 
       z (z^4 + 1), -(2 I/3) (z^6 + 1)}/(z^6 + Sqrt[5] z^3 - 1) + {0, 
      0, 1/2}]]], {r, 0, 1}, {\[Theta], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
 Mesh -> {30, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Yellow}, Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> None]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
z := u + v I
g1 := -(3/2) Im[(z (1 - z^4))/(z^6 + z^3 Sqrt[5] - 1)]
g2 := -(3/2) Re[(z (1 + z^4))/(z^6 + z^3 Sqrt[5] - 1)]
g3 := Im[(1 + z^6)/(z^6 + z^3 Sqrt[5] - 1)] - 1/2
g = g1^2 + g2^2 + g3^2;
```

You could use `Piecewise` here.

When `Abs[z] > 1`, the function is undefined and plots nothing.

```
ParametricPlot3D[Piecewise[{{{g1/g, g2/g, g3/g}, Abs[z] <= 1}}, Undefined],
                 {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

I'm not an expert on `Graphics`, but I hope that helps.

Comment: You could also add the option `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, u^2 + v^2 <= 1]` instead of changing the function.

Comment: Ah, yes, both solutions worked!! Thanks so much! On a totally unrelated note, does anyone happen to know of this parametrization has 3-fold symmetry when viewed from the 'top'?

Comment: @Diego, yes, my current Gravatar does display that feature you speak of...

Answer (score 4):

Altho traditionally one should use polar coordinates as I suggested in a comment above, I found it amusing that `ParametricPlot3D[]` can actually support a region specification for specifying the domain of the parameters. Thus here is a way to plot the [Bryant-Kusner parametrization](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-1987-15564-9) of the Boy surface:

```
ParametricPlot3D[With[{z = u + I v}, (#/(#.#)) &[Re[{0, 0, 1/2} +
                      {I z (1 - z^4), z (z^4 + 1), -(2 I/3) (z^6 + 1)}/
                      (z^6 + Sqrt[5] z^3 - 1)]]], {u, v} ∈ Disk[],
                 Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> True,
                 PlotPoints -> {20, 30}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[2/3]]
```

[image: just look at the threefold symmetry!]

where I made the surface translucent to display the inner structure. Mathematically, the construction is an inversion of a certain minimal surface that is topologically equivalent to the projective plane, thrice-punctured. See the linked paper for more background.